# if initialState will have an array of object responses, should it be initialized as null or empty array?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm building a small photo sharing app and I have the following `initialState` in my `photos` reducer:

```
{
  photos: null
  category: null
}
```

From my API, I will be receiving a response like this:

```
{
  category: 'Animals & Nature',
  photos: [{ id: 1001, url: 'cdn.url.com/img1001', title: 'dog' }, { id: 1002, url: 'cdn.url.com/img1002', title: 'cat' }
}
```

Since `photos` will be an array of objects, should my initial state have it as `null` or `[]`?

Also, if I get more photos, I will need to concat them to the state.photos..

How to best handle in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to initialize an array to `[]` instead of `null`. There are many advantages to this approach. At least one of the advantages is - "**You cannot invoke the methods of null object** For(e.g.), you will not able to check length of a Array whose value is null. But, you sure can check the value of an empty array.

```js
var arr = [];
console.log("Array Length - " + arr.length); //Length - 0
```

and now try this snippet below

```js
var arr = null;
console.log("Array Length - " + arr.length); //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this, but I'd add the caveat that initializing to `null` could make sense if `photos === null` and `photos.length === 0` have different semantic meanings, for example, if the two states distinguish between a query that hasn't been performed and one with an empty result set.